# Muting the Volume of my Visual Basic Application

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a program in VB that will respond to voice commands, for various things. As it is right now, it has a voice Synthesizer that will state the command that it hears, but I want the option to issue a command to mute it.

I know the voice recognition part of the program, I simply don't know the command to mute the program. Mind you, I only want to mute the Visual Basic application, not my computer's sound, and I also want a separate command for unmuting.

Currently the voice synth is set up like so:

```
    Private Sub reco_SpeechRecognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionEventArgs) Handles reco.SpeechRecognized

    Dim synth As New Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

    Select Case e.Result.Text
```

In which all of the cases are the various commands I can issue to the program, and the synthesizer says a line for each one.

I have no idea how to go about doing so, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the SpeechSynthesizer object have a Volume property? `synth.Volume = 0`

Comment: @HanletEscaño, evidently, that is the case. Thank you for that, I'm unfamiliar with the speech library.

Comment: You could always read the documentation for it. :-)